# Trying to switch images using a toggle button in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, toggle

I'm not quite sure why my code isn't working at this point. I am trying to make an Instagram like button. I have an image of a black heart and when double clicked on I want to switch it to another image of a red heart. I've dug around here and there but couldn't quite pin point the problem. The code snippet works but it does not work when I run it in my project.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#like');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
    if (button.src == "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg") {
        button.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
    } else {
        button.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg";
    }
});
```

```css
.under-image-nav button {
    border: none;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="under-image-nav">
    <button><img id="like" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="like button">           </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the event listener to the button instead.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('#like');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
    if (img.src == "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg") {
        img.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg";
    } else {
        img.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
    }
});
```

```html
<button><img id="like" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="like button" width="100" height="100"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually edited my code block, it was missing the button const to which I assigned it the appropriate query selector.

Comment: @Verde92 What type of element is `#like`? Could you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: it is an img tag wrapped by a button tag: 

<button><img id="like" src="../image/heart like.png" alt="like button"></button>

Comment: @Verde92 I've updated my answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: unfortunately, not. I changed my html and js to match yours and it is still not working.

Comment: @Verde92 Please provide a [mcve]. Does the snippet itself work?

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code snippet. It works there but no in my project.

Comment: @Verde92 That's not a [mcve] if it does not show the error. I can't help if I can't produce the problem for myself.

Comment: I got it to work. The paths I was using were relative paths (../image/picture.png) and the way I fixed it is I put paths like this http://127.0.0.1:5500...

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the button and simply allowed javascript to control the source of the image.

To shorten the code, I used a ternary operator

```js
let heartEl = document.querySelector(".heart");
const fullHeart = 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ffrogermcs.github.io%2Fimages%2F6%2Fheart_red.png&f=1&nofb=1"'
const emptyHeart = 'https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/heart-outline.png'

heartEl.addEventListener("dblclick", () => {
  heartEl.src ==  emptyHeart ? heartEl.src = fullHeart : heartEl.src = emptyHeart
});
```

```html
<img class='heart' src='https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/heart-outline.png'>
```